# three js add light onclick

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have properly loaded sphere mesh with Lambert material.

I want to add light source on the point where i have click intersection.

`target` = clicked object.
`to` = vector3 of my click.

on dblclick event listener i do:

```
var newLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0x808F8F,20 );
newLight.position.set(to.x,to.y,to.z);
scene.add( newLight );
newLight.updateMatrix();
newLight.updateMatrixWorld();
target.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

But nothing happens, light is visible only when i add antoher object to the scene, not on my clicked target object.

How i force recalculating of light sources on target object?

Comment: it is a part of bigger ajax code, will be extemly time consuming make new scene for fiddle. I think i missed up something primitive.

Answer (score 0):

i had a very similar problem recently, you need to update all materials affected by the light.
for example:

```
for(i in scene.children){
    if(scene.children[i].material) scene.children[i].material.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

Comment: Thi, thx for advice, is here some difference between this and my command? : target.material.needsUpdate = true; I need to see lights only on the taget objects don care about rest of the scene.

Comment: did you also notice you add minerLight instead of newLight?

Comment: Yes I wrote exaple by hand, in my code was it correct. I corrected question.